# can't open MySQLWorkbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

i have a problem with mysql workbench, after i installed it, i can't open it! it was always show message "**mysql workbench has stopped working**" and the detail is

> Problem signature:
>
> Problem Event Name:  APPCRASH
>
> Application Name:   MySQLWorkbench.exe
>
> Application Version:    5.2.42.9752
>
> Application Timestamp:  50243f32
>
> Fault Module Name:  KERNELBASE.dll
>
> Fault Module Version:   6.1.7600.16850
>
> Fault Module Timestamp: 4e21132b
>
> Exception Code: e0434352
>
> Exception Offset:   00009673
>
> OS Version: 6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1
>
> Locale ID:  1033
>
> Additional Information 1:   0a9e
>
> Additional Information 2:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
>
> Additional Information 3:   0a9e
>
> Additional Information 4:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Comment: This is a question for [superuser](http://superuser.com/)

Comment: try this: http://www.mandsconsulting.com/resolving-mysql-workbench-has-stopped-working-error-message-workbench-v5-2-windows-event-id-1026-and-1000

Answer (score 3):

Try installing it with installing the MSVC2010 x86 redistributables (even if you're running a x64 box) before. See [this bug report here](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=62065) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Issue resolved by end-user as follows:

1. Uninstall MySQL Workbench.

   Before doing step 2. One must enable "Hidden Files And Folders". or simply type the path using "run": C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\
2. Rename C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench\
   to C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench_old\
3. Reinstall Workbench.

Comment: The rename doesn't do anything. The new name is the same as the old one: C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench\

Answer (score 1):

MySQL Workbench also requires:

- [Microsoft .NET 4.0 Framework](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17113)
- [Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable Package (MSVC2013)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784)

Install both the above packages and you're good to go.

Source: [MySQL installation document.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-installing-windows.html)

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and error msg in my Windows 8 development machine.

I wanted to have a shortcut to MySQLWorkbench in the desktop so I copied the shortcut directly from the start menu. It turns out that instead of copying the shortcut it copied the actual MySQLWorkbench.exe file.

I just created a new shortcut and everything started to work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Installing the MSVC2010 x86 plus downloading msvcr100.dll into system32 solved the problem both for installer and zip variant.